# Regex returning undesired value

Tags: regex, powershell, cisco-ios

I am trying to create a script that will comb through a Cisco "show run all" file and return an interface based on if a command appears. I have a start of Regex, but it's matching on the previous interface and not the desired interface.

My regex is `interface (\S+)(?s).*?access-session port-control force-authorized`

Sample information below. The desired result would be `GigabitEthernet1/0/45`, but instead it is returning `GigabitEthernet1/0/44`.

Sample Data:

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/44  
access-session port-control auto 
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/45  
access-session port-control force-authorized
```

Comment: This question doesn't need debugging details: it's easy to [verify that the regex doesn't work as intended](https://regex101.com/r/JLwDu0/1), and the intent is stated.
It does, however, need an accepted answer that isn't demonstrably broken.

Comment: You mean like my answer, contrived by me because y'all can't get over yourselves, that works in production exactly as intended?

Comment: Your answer is _broken_: it doesn't and cannot work with the sample data in your question - [you've been given a link that proves that](https://regex101.com/r/z9aiiz/1) - and is generally conceptually flawed (you've also been given a corrected version). The only thing that matters on this site is to have focused questions with equally focused _matching_ solutions. In short: Your answer doesn't solve the problem presented in your question, and you're doing future readers a disservice by letting it stand as is. (That it may work _for you_ in some - unknown - _different_ scenario is irrelevant.)

Comment: On a meta note @aric8456, let us review your actions here:

Comment: You originally posted a poorly formatted question. I tried to fix the formatting, and - due to the ambiguous original formatting -
I accidentally introduced an _extra newline_ and based the original form of my answer on that (which still solved the problem as stated).
Instead of providing feedback on and/or fixing the formatting, you posted an answer that didn't match the original sample data in the question.
When that was pointed out to you, you pushed back based on the _incidental_ aspect of the formatting artifact, while acknowledging that a crucial part was missing from the sample data.

Comment: You then fixed the incidental formatting problem in the question and added the crucial part, while ignoring the concrete feedback demonstrating that your solution was broken even with the updated sample data.
You then briefly accepted accepted a different answer before doubling down on your own, broken one.
Instead of addressing the feedback regarding how your answer is broken, you then decided to post a needlessly cantankerous comment about how "y'all can't get over yourselves".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so as I thought I was close, but here is what works. Basically I had to tell it to stop matching at the ! which separates the interface config within the config file. (adding [^!] )

```
interface (\S+)(?s)[^!].*?access-session port-control force-authorized
```

Comment: Note that your answer is broken even for the updated data in the question, as demonstrated by [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/z9aiiz/1)

Comment: For the record: I up-voted your _question_, and it wasn't I who down-voted your _answer_. The existing down-votes - as well as the close votes - are likely an  expression of the currently [prevailing culture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) in the [tag:regex] tag. That said, unless we come to a shared understanding about your answer being broken, I will down-vote your answer (but not your question) too.

Comment: I've added a corrected version of your own attempt to my answer - but, as stated, there's no need for such a complex solution (unless the sample input data in the question is still not representative).

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will do (replace `(?s).*?` with `\s+`):

```bash
interface (\S+)\s+access-session port-control force-authorized
```

- For an explanation and the option to experiment with this regex, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/z9aiiz/3).
- You don't need [inline option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions) `(?s)` (which makes `.` match newlines too), given that `\s` matches a newline char. too and given that all you need to match is *whitespace*.
- By not matching a run of *any* characters via `.*?`, there is no need to then *exclude* characters, as in [your own solution attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77447678/45375).

  - Here's a [fixed version of your own attempt](https://regex101.com/r/L8ZPG5/4) - but note that there's no need for this complexity (unless your sample data isn't truly representative of your real data):

    ```bash
    interface (\S+)[^!]+?access-session port-control force-authorized
    ```

    - `[^!]+?` non-greedily matches any nonempty run of characters (including newlines) *not* containing `!`, and thereby prevents matching across the `!` char. in the input.

---

As for **what you tried**:

- `interface (\S+)` starts matching at the *first* `interface` block, and `.*?` then successfully matches any text *across the subsequent* `interface` block until the `access-session port-control force-authorized` text is found. That is, you therefore capture the *first* interface block's name, not that of the one the text of interest is associated with.

  - See [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/z9aiiz/2) for a demonstration.
- In other words: using the *non-greedy* form of `.*`, `.*?`, does *not* protect you from matching the preceding subexpression (`interface (\S+)`) *again*  (given that *any* run of characters is matched) before the (closest, due to the non-greediness) succeeding one (`access-session port-control force-authorized`) is matched.

---

A **complete PowerShell example** (note that the input must be provided *as a single, multiline string*, given that you want to match *across lines*):

```bash
$str = @'
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/44  
access-session port-control auto 
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/45  
access-session port-control force-authorized
'@ 

if ($str -match 'interface (\S+)\s+access-session port-control force-authorized') {
  # Output what the 1st capture group matched.
  $Matches.1
}
```

The above outputs `'GigabitEthernet1/0/45'`, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following *match pattern*.

```
(?<=interface ).+?(?=\s+access-session port-control force-authorized)
```

Or, *capture pattern*.

```
interface (.+?)\s+access-session port-control force-authorized
```